# Which is easiest solution for hover images

Tags: jquery

I am looking for some easy jquery solution for hover images.

Like if i define a class. them jquery should get the current image like

abc.png then chnage that to abc_on.png

and then put that to on hover image

How can i do that.

i don't want to add function for every button.

Just one function and it do all.

My Images all usually imagename.png or imagename_on.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('img.class').hover(function() {
   var obj = $(this); 
   obj.attr('src', obj.attr('src').replace('.png', '_on.png'));
}, function () {
   var obj = $(this); 
   obj.attr('src', obj.attr('src').replace('_on.png', '.png'));
});
```

I haven't had a chance to try it, but it should work, as long as .png does not show up in the filename elsewhere.

Edit:
A solution that is a little more expensive using regular expressions:

```
var onRe = new RegExp('\\.(.*)$');
var offRe = new RegExp('_on\\.(.*)$');
$('img.class').hover(function() {
   var obj = $(this);
   obj.attr('src', obj.attr('src').replace(onRe, '_on.$1'));
}, function () {
   var obj = $(this);
   obj.attr('src', obj.attr('src').replace(offRe, '.$1'));
});
```

Comment: you should avoid selecting `$(this)` twice. you could use $that = $(this) and then youe $that.attr() etc..

Comment: I was feeling a little lazy for the example, but you are right, I've updated the code.

Comment: that was  good but can you please chnage the code that if the image extension can be any like gif, jpg etc, then it shoulk also work

Comment: Updated answer to add one that should work with any extension type. I would suggest next time to include that kind of info in your question, yours just asked about png